# TomEE 7 embedded - redirect all traffic to HTTPS

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee, tomee-7

How can I configure embedded TomEE 7 server to force HTTPS without performing the redirect at the Servlet level, but instead do it at Container level? I have 2 connectors, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

Here's my HTTP connector.

```
Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
        connector.setAttribute("protocol", "HTTP/1.1");
        connector.setAttribute("maxThreads", "200");
        connector.setAttribute("protocol", "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol");
        connector.setAttribute("redirectPort", "443");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could configure your `web.xml` in order to do that:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Automatic Forward to HTTPS/SSL
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
       <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

More information [here](https://gist.github.com/jtgasper3/10501274).

Comment: im aware of this, but im looking for a way to make the web container do HTTPS redirects, not the web application. if i have 10 WARs, i need to modify 10 web.xml and always have to do it for each new one. the `redirectPort` Connector attribute is supposed to do it, but it doesnt